# get cursor from array

Tags: android, string, arrays, cursor

Is it possible to get an android cursor from an array (either `ArrayList` or `StringaArray`)?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could subclass AbstractCursor;

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You can use arrays as adaptors, and you can jump like in Cursors. Tell us first why you need that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loxley has one solution: create your own `Cursor` class, extending `AbstractCursor`, to wrap around your collection.

Another option to not create an `ArrayList`, but instead create a `MatrixCursor`.